# Adding HTML & Javascript Code AND Using Plug In for Transition Effects in Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-plugins, slideshow, transition

I am trying to add transition effects for a clients web site. I already have the slideshow code up and working perfectly but client wants effects when the images change. This is the plug in and effect I found: http://www.jqueryscript.net/slideshow/Tiny-jQuery-Image-Slideshow-with-Slice-Transition-Effect-slydify.html
I followed all of the instructions, and when I re freshed the page the slideshow was either gone or each image showed on top of each other, rather than a slideshow. I think the main reason this is not working is because I am putting the ID "slider" maybe in the wrong place? I am also a junior web designer and was not designing for 4 months, so I think I may be doing some minor thing wrong. If anyone can help that would be super awesome. I am so frustrated trying to get this to work!

This is my slideshow code:(without the "slider" ID)

```
  <!-- Main Carousel -->
  <section class="section background-dark">
    <div class="line">

      <div class="carousel-fade-transition owl-carousel carousel-main carousel-nav-white carousel-wide-arrows">

        <div class="item">
          <div class="s-12 center">
            <img src="img/01-boxed.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-content">
              <div class="padding-2x">
                <div class="s-12 m-12 l-8">
                  <p class="text-white text-s-size-20 text-m-size-40 text-l-size-60 margin-bottom-40 text-thin text-line-height-1">Pacific Earthworks</p>
                  <p class="text-white text-size-16 margin-bottom-40">Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit<br> esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis</p>  
                </div>                  
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!--End item-->

        <div class="item">
          <div class="s-12 center">
            <img src="img/02-boxed.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-content">
              <div class="padding-2x">
                <div class="s-12 m-12 l-8">
                  <p class="text-white text-s-size-20 text-m-size-40 text-l-size-60 margin-bottom-40 text-thin text-line-height-1">Excavation, Infrastructure and Civil Works</p>
                  <p class="text-white text-size-16 margin-bottom-30">Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis</p>    
                </div>                  
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!--end item-->

        <div class="item">
          <div class="s-12 center">
            <img src="img/03-boxed.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-content">
              <div class="padding-2x">
                <div class="s-12 m-12 l-8">
                  <p class="text-white text-s-size-20 text-m-size-40 text-l-size-60 margin-bottom-40 text-thin text-line-height-1">Here For All of Your Landscaping Needs</p>
                  <p class="text-white text-size-16 margin-bottom-30">Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis</p>    
                </div>                  
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!--end item-->


      </div> 

    </div>

  </section>

</main>
```

Comment: Can you also share the javascript you were using?

Comment: This is at the end of my head section: <!-- Slideshow animation css and js-->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slydify.css">-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/slydify.js"></script>
<script>
2
$(function() {
3
$("#slider").slydify();
4
});
5
</script>

Comment: It looks like you copy and pasted directly from that website and included invalid characters. Remove the 2, 3, 4, 5 text, those were line numbers from the code snippet you picked up. You should be able to just put the slider id on the section at the top and the plugin will grab all the images and make a slideshow. I doubt this is what you want, because all your text will show all the time and only the images will rotate. You will need additional scripts to rotate the entire "item" node, or find a different plugin.

Comment: The comments will not let me put in my full code saying it is too long. Sorry if this makes it harder as I am new to this website and joined to get help when I needed it as a new web designer.

Comment: I have followed EVERY step on the website where I got the plug in and the instructions how to use it: http://www.jqueryscript.net/slideshow/Tiny-jQuery-Image-Slideshow-with-Slice-Transition-Effect-slydify.html

Comment: Can I see your jQuery code?

Answer (score 0):

Add the slider id to the section node like this

```
<section class="section background-dark" id="slider">
```

then for the scripts just do.

```
<script>
$(function() { 
    $("#slider").slydify();
});
</script>
```

Based on your comment above it seems like you copy and pasted directly from the websites code snippet and it included line numbers (the 2,3,4,5 you see).

The problem is this plugin won't accomplish what you are trying to achieve anyways. It only detects the  tags and just rotates through those, so all of your text will be displayed all of the time. I suggest finding another plugin that does exactly what you need, or you will need to write just custom javascript to add additional functionality

Comment: I just did this now, but my code is broken now. The images are now showing as being one on top of the other and no slideshow. I see what I did wrong with the script now. After a few months not coding it is not easy getting my head back into it. But it still is not working. I will keep tweaking around and see if I can get it to work. Thanks.